# Помогите разобраться с кодом js

Tags: javascript

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, такая проблемка, на js редактирую код, не могу понять, создала две кнопки:

```
{
    type: "label",
    list: [ {
            type: "newcolumn",
        }, {
            type: "button",
            name: "info_button",
            value: "Подробнее"
             }]
    }, {
    type: "label",
    list: [ {
            type: "newcolumn",
        }, {
            type: "button",
            name: "new_object",
            value: "Добавить"
        }]
}];
```

Смысл в том, что должно быть при  нажатии на них два разных всплывающих окна. 
Скрипт всплывающего окна:

```
myForm.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(name) {
    showObjectInfo();
});    
myForm.lock();
putObjectsAmount();
info_window = dhxWins.createWindow("InfoWin", 0, 0, 600, 500);
info_window.setText("Подробная информация");
info_window.denyResize();
//info_window.denyMove();
info_window.button("minmax1").hide();
info_window.button("park").hide();
info_window.keepInViewport(true);
info_window.attachObject("obj_adv_info");
info_window.attachEvent("onClose", hideInfoWindow);    
//info_window.setModal(true);
error_window = dhxWins.createWindow("ErrorWin", 0, 0, 470, 155);
error_window.setText("Ошибка!");
error_window.denyResize();
error_window.denyMove();
error_window.button("minmax1").hide();
error_window.button("park").hide();
error_window.button("close").hide();
error_window.centerOnScreen();
error_window.keepInViewport(true);
error_window.progressOn();
error_window.attachObject("net_error");

info_window.hide();
error_window.hide();

showObjects();
showSims();
```

Оно прикреплено к кнопке, но при нажатии второй кнопки оно всплывает так же, подскажите, сколько читаю код, не могу понять при, помощи какого скрипта в этом безобразии обозначено, что оно прикреплено к кнопке, как их разделить? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Чет у вас всё очень плохо... Нормально отредактируйте вопросю

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, что я не могу понять, почему после того как я создала новую кнопку и прописи на нее скрипта на новое всплывающее окно у меня при нажатии всплывает то, которое обращается к первой кнопке